# Input style problem in html really unusual

Tags: html, css

I have a question. Why does the style on the input (border-color) make me make this dark green line? it should be all light green!

```
.contact .contact-content input[type=text]{
width: 100%;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-color: rgb(0, 255, 72);
border-radius: 5px;
border-width: 3px;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

[picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTobe.png)

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing a [mcve]

Comment: It might be because of the outline.

Comment: sorry, by mistake I didn't put the code in the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because you haven't added the border style to the input. The border style for elements is set *inset* by default. Take a look at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style).

```css
input[type=text]{
width: 100%;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 5px;
/* border-color: rgb(0, 255, 72);
border-width: 3px;
border-style: solid; */
/* Use shorthand method */
border: 3px solid rgb(0, 255, 72);
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the border style property is on inset. If that's the case you should change it to solid : `border-style: solid;` instead of `border-style : inset;`